# File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module> - ImportError: No module named roslaunch

Tags: ros

getting the following error with ROS Ubuntu 16 lts, when using roslaunch:

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in  - ImportError: No module named roslaunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following command:
source ./devel/setup.bash